# Python: Ask to user a list var

Tags: python, list, binary, var

I'm a french newbie in Python. I'm building a program who convert binary number (8bits) in decimal number.
I'm here:

```
s=0 
a=int(input()) 
b=int(input()) 
c=int(input()) 
d=int(input())
e=int(input()) 
f=int(input()) 
g=int(input()) 
h=int(input())
L=[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h] 
for x in range(8):
    a=L[x]*(2**(7-x))
    s=s+a 
print(s)
```

But I would like the user have to tap his binary number directly (F.e: "01011101"), and not as I did, where the user have to tap the fist number, then enter, the second, then enter......

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Joran Beasley noted, in your particular case, you can simply use `int` transform your script into a one-liner (though he chose to use two for clarity).

However, here is how you would condense all those `int(input())`'s like you want:

```
s=0
L=[int(c) for c in input()]
for x in range(8):
    a=L[x]*(2**(7-x))
    # This is the same as "s=s+a"
    s+=a 
print(s)
```

Basically, use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

*Note:* You could also do `list(map(int, input()))`, but I personally think the list comprehension is cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

```
numeric_base = 2
print int(raw_input("Enter Binary Number:"),numeric_base)
```

or in python 3

```
print( int(input("enter binary number:"),numeric_base) )
```

you could also do hex and use `numeric_base=16` or octal and use `numeric_base=8`

Comment: Thanks for your help, I didn't know this command "numeric base" !